# How do I use python variable in a javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, webdriver

I've been on a prowl looking for a way to access a non visible text field using selenium's webdriver. The only way i got it to work is using

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('text_field').value+='XYZ'")
```

However, instead of using `XYZ`, I want to use python variables.

Answer (score 8):

The normal way to pass variables to the JavaScript code you execute through Selenium is to just pass the variables to `execute_script`:

```
foo = "something"
driver.execute_script("""
var foo = arguments[0];
document.getElementById('text_field').value += foo;
""", foo)
```

You retrieve the argument on the JavaScript side through the [`arguments` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments). You can do this because the code you pass to `execute_script` is wrapped in a function so what is executed is something like:

```
function () {
    var foo = arguments[0];
    document.getElementById('text_field').value += foo;
}
```

and the function is called with the arguments that were passed to `execute_script`. The arguments are serialized automatically by Selenium.

Interpolating with `.format` or concatenating strings are fragile ways to do it. For instance if you do `'var foo = "' + foo + '"'` this will break as soon as your `foo` variable has a double quote in it (same with `'var foo = "{0}"'.format(foo)`). Using `json.dumps` is going to avoid this and will work in most cases but it does not take care of something like this:

```
el = driver.find_element(".something")

// Do stuff with el on the Python side.

driver.execute_script("""
var el = arguments[0];
// Do something with el on the JavaScript side.
""")
```

Selenium knows how to convert the Python object it gives you when you find an object to a DOM object on the JavaScript side. `json.dumps` does not do this.

Answer (score 3):

You need to obtain a JavaScript string representation of your Python variable's value, and insert that into your JavaScript command. Fortunately, Python's `json` module will do this for you.

```
from json import dumps

driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('text_field').value+=" +
                      dumps(my_python_variable))
```

I would be wary of just inserting the value into the quote marks as other answers have shown. What if the value already has quote marks in it, or special characters that need escaping? What if it's not a string at all? `json.dumps` will handle all the necessary formatting and escaping for you, appropriate to the type of your variable.

Comment: Perfect answer with enough information to give me the warm and fuzzy!

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm misisng something, one option is:

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('text_field').value+='{0}'".format(foo))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding the problem correctly you are trying to pass a `var`  instead of hard coded `XYZ`

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('text_field').value+='" + var + "'");
```