# Javascript to input value into textbox instead of sendKeys() in Python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I cant use `send_Keys()` method to input values in the current website im working on.
So im trying to use javascript to input values.

i tried `click()` and `clear()` together with `send_keys()` before i decided to use javascript but to my disappointment, it didnt work.

i use the javascript code to input value below

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('CustCd').setAttribute('value', 'J590')")
```

and it worked.

But currently my code is inside a loop and the value changes, how can i replace `J590` with a variable that gets the value?

Here is the code that i tried

```
ccr_No = XLUtlis.readData(path, 'ccr', r, 1)
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('CCRNo').value=ccr_No")
```

I know its wrong, any help would be appreciated. My Javascript is weak.

Just some side note if anybody would be able to solve my `send_keys()` error.
The function only takes in the first character that i send. For example, `send_keys("J590")` gives `J`, `send_keys("J590-TE21")` gives `J-`

Comment: *"...and it worked..."* Not really; [details](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43210254/javascript-program-works-well-in-ie-but-not-in-firefox-and-chrome-to-fill-in-i). Instead: `document.getElementById('CustCd').value = 'J590';`

Comment: I don't do Python, but surely: `driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('CCRNo').value='" + ccr_No + "'")` so `ccr_No` isn't literal text in the string...? But if `ccr_No` could contain `'` or a backslash, you'll need to escape it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder `setAttribute()` will work just fine.

Comment: @Guy - Read the link, the `value` attribute and the `value` property are very different animals. `setAttribute` might work as a side effect of changing the default value, but it's not correct.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder [setAttribute](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp) *The setAttribute() method adds the specified attribute to an element* if it doesn't exist.

Comment: @Guy - Right, and the `value` **attribute** does not represent the current value of an input; it represents the *default* value of an input. There is **no** attribute that represents the *current* value, that's only gotten/set by the `value` **property**.  Again, please see [the linked question's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43210254/javascript-program-works-well-in-ie-but-not-in-firefox-and-chrome-to-fill-in-i) answers for details.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use python variable in a javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28592558/how-do-i-use-python-variable-in-a-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the correct way to set the **current** value of an input is to assign to the `value` property. There is no *attribute* for the inputs current value (the `value` attribute is the input's *default* value, [more here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43210254/javascript-program-works-well-in-ie-but-not-in-firefox-and-chrome-to-fill-in-i)).

The rest is a special case of a general-purpose question: "How do I output a Python variable's value into JavaScript code?"

**If** the string you're outputting doesn't contain quotes or backslashes, you may get away with using a format string and outputting the value in quotes [as Guy shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57849167/157247). (JavaScript has two kinds of quotes, `'` and `"`; you only need to escape the kind you use around the value.) Those kinds of assumptions tend to break down, though; as soon as the string is `Hi, I'm Joe` that approach breaks.

In the general case, to ensure proper escaping and that all values are written correctly, you can use JSON:

```python
import json
value = 'J590'
driver.execute_script(f"document.getElementById('CustCd').value = {json.dumps(value)};")
```

That outputs:

```js
document.getElementById('CustCd').value = "J590";
```

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/8oK81S)

That way, you don't have to worry about quoting and escaping, it's all handled for you since valid JSON is valid JavaScript (thanks to a recent JavaScript specification fix; prior to that there was an edge case incompatibility that people almost never ran into).

It's also useful for numbers, or more complex things you might want to pass to hte JavaScript code. For instance:

```python
import json

class Example:
    foo = ""
    bar = 0

    def __init__(self, foo, bar):
        self.foo = foo
        self.bar = bar

value = Example("I'm a string with \"quotes\" in it.", 42)
print(f"const obj = {json.dumps(value.__dict__)};")
num = 42
print(f"const num = {json.dumps(num)};")
```

That outputs:

```js
const obj = {"foo": "I'm a string with \"quotes\" in it.", "bar": 42};
const num = 42;
```

`obj` ends up being an object, because the initializer is a valid JavaScript object literal containing the data from the `Example` object. Similarly, `num` is a valid JavaScript number.

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/zJrURV)

Answer (score 1):

You need to insert the variable as variable, not literal

```
value = 'J590'
driver.execute_script(f"document.getElementById('CustCd').setAttribute('value', '{value}')")
```

Comment: Does this ensure the resulting JavaScript code has the value in quotes? Because it needs to be, it's not a number. Also, the kind of quote used (and backslashes) need escaping.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes, this is valid Python syntax.

Comment: That isn't what I asked. I asked if it would put the value in quotes and escape things properly.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It doesn't need any escaping, this is valid as it is. Python can differentiate between `"` and `'`.

Comment: It **does** require quotes, which the above doesn't produce: http://ideone.com/sv2mEr. And while the **sample** value doesn't require escaping, it's just a sample value, at least mentioning the issue is important.

Answer (score 0):

Using *Javascript* to input the values of a variable you can use the following solution:

```
ccr_No = XLUtlis.readData(path, 'ccr', r, 1)
# ccr_No = J590
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('CCRNo').value='" + ccr_No + "';")
```

An example, to input the values of a variable within *Search Box* of *Google Home Page*:

- Code Block:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
  value = 'J590'
  driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByName('q')[0].value='" + value + "';")
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: variable]

> You can find a relevant discussion in [Selenium : How to send variable character strings through executeScript()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49596978/selenium-how-to-send-variable-character-strings-through-executescript/49597079#49597079)