# Unable to open new tab with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to open each listing from eBay to scrape. My objective is to open each eBay's listing in a "for loop" so I can scrape each listing's data.

Unfortunately, I get an error stating:

> selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript
>   error: link is not defined

My code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/kenny/Dropbox/Python/Web Scrapping/Others/chromedriver')
driver.get('https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=watches&_sacat=0&_pgn=1')
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
driver.maximize_window()


for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    if 'itm' in link['href']:
        print(link['href'])
        driver.execute_script("window.open(link['href'])") # Unable to open new tab of each watch to scrape each listing.
```

Entire Code: https://pastebin.com/pFdKU45d

Thank you so much. Seriously.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use python variable in a javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28592558/how-do-i-use-python-variable-in-a-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quoting is wrong:

```
driver.execute_script("window.open(\"" + link['href'] + "\")")
```